# Is Nasu a woman?

Tags: fate-stay-night

Is Nasu a woman? 
/a/ and 2ch often say that Nasu is a girl; there's also Fate/prototype that resembles an otome game, and also the fact that Nasu's pic is never shown at all.

Comment: I don't see how Fate/Prototype is Otome (since it isn't even a game, it was a novel and there are OVA), just because Ayaka is the main character and Saber and Archer vie for her affection doesn't make it Otome. as for no images, it's probably out of respect that no one takes a photo of during the Q&A Events.

Comment: That's typical 4chan sarcasm.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinoko_Nasu), he's a male.

> Kinoko Nasu (奈須 きのこ Nasu Kinoko?, male, born 28 November 1973) is a Japanese author, best known for writing the novel Kara no Kyōkai and visual novels Tsukihime and Fate/stay night.

Citing a blog post from July 2004: http://www.typemoon.org/bbb/diary/log/200407.html

Comment: also the [TYPE-MOON Wikia](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Kinoko_Nasu) refers to him as a "he"